# tcl/itcl - foreach iteration on args input list with two arguments

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have the following code I wrote that should do iteration on my args input list with reading two arguments every iteration. The problem that it isn't working the way I wrote. I looked upon the Tcl/Tk Wikipedia web page but couldn't find any helpful advice. Can I do it the way I wrote (without converting it into an array)?

```
itcl::body class::config {args} {
if {[llength $args] > 1} {
    foreach {option value} in $args {
        if {[string length $option] == 0 || [string length $value] == 0} {
            puts "Runtime error::Bad Input: option flag or value is missing"
            return
        }
        switch --$option {
            -a { 
                if { [string is integer $value -strict] } {
                    #do something
                }
            }
            -b { 
                    if { [string is integer $value -strict] } {
                    #do something
                }
            }
        }
return }
```

Comment: What is the `Tcl/Tk Wikipedia web page`?

Comment: https://wiki.tcl.tk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `in`, you just need:

```
foreach {option value} $args {
```

See documentation at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm

Answer (score 0):

Some hints.
Instead of:

```
[string length $option] == 0
```

you can also write:

```
$option == ""
```

The -strict option is redundant in this case, because you are already skipping the empty strings. Moreover, you should put the option right after "is integer":

```
string is integer -strict $value
```